# How do you plot data that's been grouped by another column?

Tags: python, plotly

I keep running into an issue where I group data by certain columns, but I cannot figure out how to plot by that data that I've grouped.

[Here is my Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeMdG.png)

For example,

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

xs = df['region'].values
ys = df['AveragePrice'].values
data = [go.Bar(
    x=xs,
    y=ys,
    marker={
        'color': ys,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis'
    }
)]

layout = {
    'xaxis': {
        'categoryorder': 'array',
        'categoryarray': [x for _, x in sorted(zip(ys, xs))]
    }
}

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
fig
```

This works, but doesn't show what I really want. ^

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
df1 = df.groupby(['region'])['AveragePrice'].mean()
xs = df1['region'].values
ys = df1['AveragePrice'].values
data = [go.Bar(
    x=xs,
    y=ys,
    marker={
        'color': ys,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis'
    }
)]

layout = {
    'xaxis': {
        'categoryorder': 'array',
        'categoryarray': [x for _, x in sorted(zip(ys, xs))]
    }
}

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
fig
```

This gives me a key error. ^

Comment: Please paste your data-frame (as text, not as an image) into your post so that others can easily test your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.reset_index()` to your `groupby` call. Without that pandas can't there is the only `pd.Series` and not a table on which you can make a call to a column such as `region`:

```
region
A    1.340
B    1.005
C    1.280
Name: AveragePrice, dtype: float64
```

So for plotting you need to convert those output from `groupby` call back to `pd.DataFrame`. Without that you can't assign `x` and `y` to columns because there is no such columns. And you will get this error:

```
KeyError: 'region'
```

With `.reset_index()`:

(`df1 = df.groupby(['region'])['AveragePrice'].mean().reset_index()`)

```
  region  AveragePrice
0      A         1.340
1      B         1.005
2      C         1.280
```

So here you get `pd.DataFrame`, on which you can operate as in your previous block of code (assign `x` to one column, `y` to another, etc.). And your code will completed and get your barchart with `region` values on `x` and mean value of all values by each `region` on `y`.